# Emacsのdiredでファイル名の頭文字で選択する方法

Tags: emacs

Emacsで、diredでディレクトリを開いた時に、<kbd>c-n</kbd>や<kbd>c-p</kbd>でファイルをひとつひとつ移動はできますが、
ファイルの頭文字を打ったら、そのファイルの行まで移動する方法はないでしょうか？

```
.
..
hello.html
test.html
```

上記ディレクトリで、<kbd>t</kbd>とタイプしたら、test.htmlの行が選択されている状態になり、
enterを押すと開くというような操作ができる方法です。

Answer (score 2):

Yuki Inoueさんの回答の補足ですが、Diredのインクリメンタルサーチ <kbd>C-s</kbd> をファイル名マッチに限定する（ファイル所有者やパーミッションにマッチさせない）設定を有効にすると便利です。

以下の設定を `.emacs` あるいは `~/.emacs.d/init.el` に追記して下さい。

```
;; t    - 常にファイル名にマッチさせる
;; dwim - カーソル位置がファイル名にある場合はファイル名マッチを有効にする
(setq dired-isearch-filenames 'dwim)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。デフォルトだとファイル所有者やパーミッションにもマッチしてしまうのですね。設定しました！

Answer (score 0):

自分がよくやるのは、 C-s でインクリメンタルサーチ起動して、それでファイル名をテキストとして検索、カーソルが選択したいファイルに移動したら enter 連打、です。回答になってるかは、若干怪しいですが…

Comment: なるほどですね。

xyzzyを使っていたので、ファイル名の頭文字だけ
打てば該当ファイルをインクリメントで辿ってくれてそれが便利だったのですが
emacsではC-sでやってみます。

ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

helm を用いるのも一つの方法かと思います
興味があるなら [初心者〜初級者のためのEmacs-Helm事始め : 前編](https://qiita.com/jabberwocky0139/items/86df1d3108e147c69e2c) の「コマンド: helm-find-files」が参考になるでしょう

Comment: ありがとうございます！helmは入れていて、c-x c-fをhelm-find-filesにバインドしていたのですが、その使い方ができることに気づきませんでした。だいぶ使いやすくなりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: さらに migemo を導入している場合は，init.el や .spacemacs などの設定ファイルに `(helm-migemo-mode 1)` を記述しておくと日本語のファイル名に対しても絞り込みができ便利になりますね．ちなみに `~/hoge` ディレクトリにあるファイル「ほげ.txt」を絞り込むときはディレクトリ `~/hoge/` において半角空白 ` ` を入れてから `ho` と入力します．つまり入力欄は `~/hoge/ ho` のような表示になります．

Comment: migemoは名称はよくみていたのですが、使ったことありません。日本語での検索に対応するものという感じでしょうか。今のところ使うことが少なそうですが覚えておきます。ありがとうございます。